# Cannot Find MOSFET Transconductance - Incredibly Confused

Tags: mosfet, transimpedance, transconductance

I am tasked to find the gain of this small signal circuit drawn in my work. I have absolutely, NO idea how the professor came up with his answer. I would e-mail him, but he doesn't respond on weekends.

The professor's answer is included. If anyone can tell me where I am messing up, I would be incredibly grateful. the channel length modulation (lamda) = 0, so the output impedance is infinite therefore an open circuit.

[image]

Comment: Vgs1 is NOT Vc. You forgot about the voltage drop across M3. Does that help?

Comment: Vc? do you mean like v common?

Comment: @willbanks The way you draw your i in Vi looks a fair bit like a C.

Comment: oh i see what you mean! let me try again

Comment: Figured it out! Thank you so much. It all makes so much sense now.